# Summarize a column in pandas data frame based on other columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a small data frame tbl:

```
         CatAreaSqKm  CatMean  CatPctFull  CatCount       CatSum  COMID                                                              
1861888       0.2439   0.0000    0.000000         0     0.000000   
1862004       0.4050  27.9765   18.222222        82  2294.072964   
1862014       0.0720  27.9765   28.750000        23   643.459490   

         UpCatAreaSqKm  UpCatMean  UpCatPctFull  UpCatCount      UpCatSum  
COMID                                                                      
1861888    105360.5349  29.177349     97.901832   114610993  3.344045e+09  
1862004    105445.4517  29.174944     97.902537   114704191  3.346488e+09  
1862014    105360.2127  29.177349     97.902093   114610948  3.344044e+09
```

I want to do the following operation:

```
tbl['WsMean'] = ((tbl.CatSum + tbl.UpCatSum)/(tbl.CatCount + tbl.UpCatCount))
```

However, if I get a zero for CatCount + UpCatCount I will be dividing by zero, so for that particular row I want to set 'WsMean' to zero but for the others I would like it to be computed for the value calculated by the statement above. How can I do this? I can only think of a statement like:

```
tbl['WsMean'] = 0
```

but that would blanket all records in the table with 0.

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dividing by zero results in a NaN value. You could use `fillna(0)` to replace the NaNs with zeros:

```
tbl['WsMean'] = ((tbl.CatSum + tbl.UpCatSum)/(tbl.CatCount + tbl.UpCatCount)).fillna(0)
```